# Extracting 8 digits from a 13 digit number into a new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 workbooks. KoCos Modems and Monthly readings. In the KoCos workbook the serial numbers are 8 digits ie.68506819 and in the Monthly Readings workbook (MR) the serial numbers are 13 digits ie 3514685068196. The extra numbers are for area and city designations. There are some older serial numbers with 8 digits in the MR workbook. I have made another column in the MR workbook for the modified serials, and I used **Flashfill** to change the serial numbers. (drop the first 4 and last one). The problem is that the numbers that were 8 digits have also been shortened?? Is there a way of only shortening the 13 digit serial numbers?

This is needed to complete the second part of my problem in Q2: Vlookup between two workbooks?

Comment: Can't you simply use `IF()` and `LEN()` here to deal with `MID()` appropriately?

Comment: Hello ArtPur, welcome to the site. As a new user, please familiarize yourself with the rules of the site here: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Also, if you want you don't need to adjust your data. Depending on your version of Excel something like `=CONCAT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CHOOSE({1,2},A1,"????"&A1&"?"),<YourSearchRange>,1,0),""))` would work?

Comment: So for those who closed the question, there **is** enough information to write an answer.

Comment: Looking to see how this would work, thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a simple version:

[image]

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=8,A1,IF(LEN(A1)=13,MID(A1,5,8)*1))
```

Note I tested for 13 characters as well...